# Property detection android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

In IOS the textview has the property detection which detects whether a string is a valid phone number, or email a link ..

This property exists in android?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your xml you can set the android:inputType of the textView for instance for email you can use

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

and for phone number you can use.

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

Comment: Input type is just a clue to the keyboard on what characters to display.  It does not ensure a valid email address.  Or phone number-  it may keep it to numerics, but won't prevent a 2 digit number.

Comment: thank for your answer

but in a textview, how to specify the type of string for the device detects it right away?

Comment: Like @GabeSechan said it only forces it to show you the right keyboard characters to display. Its a first step in keeping users from giving an invalid intput. Use android Patters added in API level 8 to check the validity of input. For example you can check the email address validity or phone number validity. If you need further explanation i can give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(target)) {
            return false;
            } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
            }
        }   
 }
```

You can use this method for email validation. If you want phone number validation you can use this method.

```
public static final boolean isValidPhoneNumber(CharSequence target) {
    if (target.length()!=10) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```